# Oracle SQL CASE with a LIKE returning a value for both scenarios when I only want a result if they have any of the criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a really simple scenario I just cannot get to work.

I have some sample data:

MyTable

```
IDNO IDCode
1    AAA
1    BBB
1    CCC
2    BBB
2    CCC
3    AAA
```

Current Code

```
SELECT DISTINCT IDNO,
CASE WHEN IDCode IN ('BBB', 'CCC') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END yesno
FROM MyTable
```

Current Output

```
IDNO    yesno
1       0
1       1
2       1
3       0
```

What I want is to return a 1 if any of the criteria is met, even if they contain a value that isn't in the CASE criteria but contain at least 1 of them.

Expected Output

```
IDNO    yesno
1       1
2       1
3       0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below using group by and max aggregation

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ca7eac048961da6b98905ab44e8f2935)

```
SELECT IDNO,
max(CASE WHEN IDCode IN ('BBB', 'CCC') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) yesno
FROM MyTable
group by IDNO
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a table of `idno` uniquely per row, then you can do:

```
select i.idno,
       (case when exists (select 1 from t where t.idno = i.idnot and t.idcode in ('BBB', 'CCC' then 1 else 0 end)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from ids i;
```

Although conditional aggregation is a fine solution, I mention this because:

- You may have `idno`s that have no `idcode`s at all, and this includes them.
- `Exists` often performs better than aggregation.
- This can fit better in a complex query where you are bringing together lots of attributes at the `idno` level.